# fstream and ostrstream is undefined

Tags: visual-c++

HI,

I am converting my project from vc6 to latest using vs 2010. I get problem on compiling my code

Error   931 error C2065: 'ostrstream' : undeclared identifier
1100    IntelliSense: identifier "fstream" is undefined

I have included the required files as told in Google

```
#if ! defined(_FSTREAM_)
    #include <fstream> 
#endif 

#if ! defined(_STRSTREAM_)      
   #include <strstream>      
#endif
```

When i press F12 on the fstream or ostrstream it takes to the respective files where these class are defined. Is there any other includes i have to do, i have been searching for this for long time with no luck :(

Thanks

Arvind

Answer (score 6):

Add these to your library list:

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget all the preprocessor stuff; it's redundant at best (the files in questiion will have reinclusion guards) and at worst an error (you're assuming the #defines used, which are arbitary). Just use code like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <strstream>
```

Also note that the **strstream** header is deprecated. You should use **sstream** instead, but note the newer classed in this file word differently to the deprecated ones).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I have tried adding code as you show, the error list shows the same errors. and all the errors are related to only these 2 objects.

Answer (score 1):

***Without using*** `namespace std;` as its good practice.

```
#include<fstream>

std::fstream fileio;
```

Where the `fileio` is the object created by fstream. The fstream class needs to be created using the std keyword as it is part of the standard library.

Hence using :  `using namespace std;`  in the code makes it work.

***NOW using*** `using namespace std;` can cause conflicts in shared libraries.

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

fstream fileio;
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was a combination of two answer. After some trial and error, fstream squiggly red lines vanished when I added,

```c
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
```